# VueJS - Component does not re-render when reactive data reference update its value

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I can't solve my problem. Recently I updated VueJS from version 3.0.5 to **3.2.38** and it seems like the whole Reactivity of the page is broken.

I have a browser game where I have separated classes/data and VueJs components.
Before update, i could easily use ref or reactive outside VueJS components and then set a reference in vueJs component to that reactive field and whenever I changed value it triggers re-render but it suddenly stopped working with the new version.

Code example might tell more:

Let's assume I have this object in class PickingPhase.ts somewhere outside VueJS

```
    public pickingPhaseProps = reactive({
        time: 0,
        phase: Shared.DRAFT_PHASES.PICK_PHASE,
        draftMode: Shared.DRAFT_TYPES.ALL_PICK,
        draftTurn: -1
    });
```

In my component i create data that refers to this exact value

```
<template>
   <div class="timmer text-shadow">
       <h1 :class="{ redText: props?.time && props.time <= 10000 }">
             {{ props?.time && Math.floor(props.time / 1000) }}
       </h1>
   /div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            props: Battle.instance?.pickingPhaseProps
        }
    }
    ...
```

Tho if I update `pickingPhaseProps` it does not trigger re-render.

```
...
this.pickingPhaseProps.time = NewValue
```

I check vue changelog but I did not find the reason why it broke after the update version. Is there something i missed?

[image: Vue-extension]

Comment: Was your app an old vue2 app that you upgraded ?

Comment: It was VueJS 3.0.5. Maybe very early or alpha Vue3 that could be similar to Vue2 probably.

Comment: Because i think prior to 3.2 there was some retrocompatibility with vue2 in place, that was later dropped

Comment: I don't think it can work like that, because of the way reactivity works in vue 3, with Proxy, try to use the markRaw function : `props: markRaw(Battle.instance?.pickingPhaseProps)`, you will need to import it. https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw

Comment: Is a workaround to do... defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
        return {
            time: computed(() =>Battle.instance?.pickingPhaseProps?.time)
        }
    })

Comment: hey @Lk77 thanks for your help! I tried markRaw, it did not work, it removes "reactivity" flag in Vuejs extension. But it updated the time only when i updated different data() that triggers re-render.

Comment: @cefn Thanks for your idea, i tried your idea but it looks like i have still same problem. It says it is reactive but component does not re-render if the value is updated outside component

Comment: You will need to retrieve the proxy from the component im afraid, try to do : `Battle.instance.pickingPhaseProps = this.props` on mounted hook, now you should have the same proxy instance on both side and it should work